# Pillow does not preseve PNG info like gamma?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, png

I don't have an example image at this time, but essentially, if i encountered a situation where images loaded and then saved, without modification, changes brightness.
I read a issue where this could be because the image uses CMYK mode, but the images open in RGB mode. (I am using PNG images, which again are frames extracted from a video using ffmpeg)
After opening and then saving an image, it goes from 1.6 MB to 1.2 MB in size.
Quick sample code:

```
from PIL import Image  # Version 7.1.2

img = Image.open('.\\temp\\original.png')
print(img2.mode) # RGB
img.save('.\\temp\\test.png') # This is darker than original
```

I found out the original carries this info, using the `img.info` attribute:

```
{'aspect': (1, 1), 'chromaticity': (0.3127, 0.329, 0.64, 0.33, 0.3, 0.6, 0.15, 0.06), 'gamma': 0.50994}
```

The saved images do not. Amazed Pillow doesn't actually  save this info with new images, and i'm looking for a way to get around it. Another SO suggestion has not worked:

```
from PIL import Image

img = Image.open('1.png')
png_info = img.info
img.save('2.png', **png_info)
```

Per documentation, `.save()` doesn't seem to support adding this info, and i am looking for a way around it, ideally something that still let me convert images to RGB Pytorch tensors just as easily. (And back again.)

Update: 
Link to example image where this issue occurs: Opening and saving this will make it darker.

https://mega.nz/file/0AYwAQRJ#MrhtkDKN-EGj25eld2SrZO0GPrMDQlaz7rtVaQ-GtXs

Comment: Please try to find one example image with that issue and add it to the question.

If you're lucky you find somebody who knows the answer. Most people however would like to be able to reproduce the issue, try out some things an then after testing (if the idea really works) post an answer. That's tricky without an example image

Comment: @gelonida I have linked an image, i hope the use of mega is fine, i am not sure if uploading if in other ways could lead to the image being reencoded.

Comment: I have since put a little more effort into a way of doing this without external utilities... https://stackoverflow.com/a/71600739/2836621

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why PIL/Pillow is failing/declining to preserve/save your gamma info, but you can maybe work around it with `pngcheck` and `pngcrush`.

You can get the gAMA chunk with:

```
pngcheck -v sonic.png | grep gAMA
chunk gAMA at offset 0x00066, length 4: 0.50994
```

And you can set it, to say 0.9, after PIL has lost it with:

```
pngcrush -replace_gamma 0.9 INPUT.PNG OUTPUT.PNG
```

Comment: This method works, and marking as solved due to that. It's not an ideal solution, but i can live with it. Used the -m and -l flags at 1 to pick a fast compression method as i value speed.