# Pillow's save method ignores info parameters

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, png

I want to read, manipulate then save a png image while keeping its original `info` properties mainly `gamma`. I'm using `Pillow` version `9.0.1`

Code from SO mentions it can be done like this:

```
from PIL import Image
img = Image.open("sample.png") # Sample image provided below code block
info = img.info
img.save("output.png", **info)
```

[Sample image](https://mega.nz/file/z9dVVSzb#yUsFVJHi3Q9xCgvHrVyyBRu4exoy0JhbtD8Fi8TonC0)

But `info` does not carry over; the images no longer look alike due to the loss of the `gamma` info and further evident using the test:

```
# Test
output_info = Image.open("output.png").info
print(info)                  # {'gamma': 2147.48365}
print(output_info)           # {}
print(output_info == info)   # False, should be True
```

The question: Why does PIL's `Image.save` *not* write `gamma`?

It's not specific to `gamma`, no other chunk get written like `chromaticity` and `text`.

---

`sample.png` compared to `output.png` (as viewed using a gAMA-aware viewer, like chromium)
[image: original.png on the left, output.png on the right]

Comment: *"... without using PngInfo..."* do you mean the `PngInfo` within PIL? And what's the objection to that please?

Comment: @MarkSetchell I don't want to wrangle bytes and deal with standards. ```Image.save```'s ```pnginfo``` parameter should be enough, but it isn't. And I'm asking why that is the case. I think I might've implied that I need a solution to embed gamma info which I don't.

Comment: Maybe raise an issue on the PIL Github repository in that case... and add a link here for other folks to find.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Will do. Just thought this case had different documented semantics I just didn't know of. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like my expectations were wrong. PIL's PNG file writer does not support a `gamma` keyword argument therefore it is being silently ignored. Exactly as documented:

- No mention of a `gamma` parameter after the quoted line under PIL's [PNG file format documentation](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/handbook/image-file-formats.html#png):

> The save() method supports the following options:

- [`Image.save`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.save) ignores unrecognized keyword arguments:

> Keyword options can be used to provide additional instructions to the writer. If a writer doesn’t recognise an option, it is silently ignored.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way of doing what you ask, without using anything external.  It inserts a **gAMA** chunk as follows:

- it gets **PIL** to encode the image into an *"in-memory"* PNG
- it opens the output file on disk in binary mode
- it then takes the 8-byte PNG signature created by **PIL** and writes it to disk
- likewise the 25-byte **IHDR** created by **PIL**
- then it creates a **gAMA** chunk with your value, prepends the length, appends a CRC and writes to disk
- then it copies the remainder of the **PIL** generated image to disk

---

**Note**: The PNG Specification stipulates that the signature must come first, then the **IHDR** chunk. It also stipulates that **gAMA** must come before **IDAT**, so there is no reason my code should create an invalid PNG unless:

- **PIL** suddenly starts generating **gAMA** chunks, which would lead to multiple such chunks and would be illegal - but we are only doing this precisely because PIL does not write **gAMA** chunks, or
- an unreasonable gamma value is provided, or
- some aspect of writing to on-disk PNG fails due to disk full or other I/O error.

---

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import zlib
import struct
from io import BytesIO
from PIL import Image

def savePNGwithGamma(im, filename, gamma):
   """Save the image as PNG with specified gamma"""

   # Encode as PNG into memory buffer
   buffer = BytesIO()
   im.save(buffer, 'PNG')

   # Seek back to start of in-memory PNG
   buffer.seek(0)
   # Open output file in binary mode
   with open(filename, 'wb') as fd:
      # Read 8-byte PNG signature from memory and write to on-disk PNG
      signature = buffer.read(8)
      fd.write(signature)
      # Read 25-byte PNG IHDR chunk from memory and write to on-disk PNG
      IHDR = buffer.read(25)
      fd.write(IHDR)

      # Create our lovely new gAMA chunk - https://www.w3.org/TR/2003/REC-PNG-20031110/#11gAMA
      # Network byte ordering, scale factor of 100000
      gAMA = b'gAMA' + struct.pack('!I',int(gamma*100000))
      # 4-byte length, gAMA chunk, 4-byte CRC
      gAMA = struct.pack('!I', 4) + gAMA + struct.pack('!I', zlib.crc32(gAMA))
      # Insert into on-disk PNG after IHDR and before anything else such as PLTE, IDAT, IEND
      fd.write(gAMA)

      # Write remainder of PNG from memory to disk
      fd.write(buffer.read())

################################################################################
# main
################################################################################

# Load sample image
im = Image.open('sample.png')

# Save with desired gamma
savePNGwithGamma(im, 'result.png', 2.2)
```

Comment: I really do appreciate the high effort answer but that's not what I'm looking for. I have read [your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62387041/17595968) from 2 years ago where you mention "I don't know why Pillow is failing to save your gamma info" which is what I want to know. I apologize, my question might've not been clear.